# is it better/faster to paint an image as the background of a button or use the Java2D to paint it

Tags: java, swing, button, drawing, java-2d

Say I have a button and want to change the background button to a gradient, is it better/faster to draw a gradient using Java2D or just get an image with that gradient and put it in the background of the button?

Answer (score 1):

The only way to tell if something is faster is to measure it. As changing a button's background color varies by look & feel, I like to implement the [`Icon`](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/Icon.html) interface in order to decorate a button, as suggested in this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3072979).

Answer (score 1):

Best answer: Measure it and see.

Realistic answer: Doesn't really matter. Screen refresh rate is usually the more important factor.

Best solution: Use some form of double buffering to make the question irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that it is important to measure it and see.  From my experience, painting a gradient is likely going to be slower than painting an image.  However, if you are only talking about a small button, it may not make enough difference to worry about.  There are some tricks to speed up gradients.  For instance, you can paint it to a BufferedImage and whenever you need to paint your gradient use *g.drawImage(Image img, int x, int y, ImageObserver observer)* instead of creating a new gradient.  Even more, if your gradient is straight up and down, you can store the gradient in a BufferedImage of 1 pixel width.   Then you can paint the gradient across the entire width of your background using *g.drawImage(Image img, int x, int y, int width, int height, ImageObserver observer)*.

However, worrying about which is faster is generally pointless though if one takes 1 millisecond and the other takes 0.1 millisecond (unless you are trying to call it 1000 times a second of course).  For more information I would recommend the book Filthy Rich Clients, especially chapters 4, 5, and 7.